# How to install dockbarx?

Tags: docky

I just need a link to install dockbarx that's all please could someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/DockbarX?content=101604
this is what you need. nit also has extra themes
enjoy.

Comment: And how to run it ?? in Ubuntu 11.10 i only see dockbarx preference in the dash

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried the main WebUpd8 PPA? To add it and install DockBarX, use the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dockbarx dockbarx-themes-extra
```

[image]

To also install the AWN applet, use:

```
sudo apt-get install awn-applet-dockbarx
```

Since DockBarX used to be a GNOME 2.3x panel applet which isn't available anymore in Ubuntu 11.10, I assume you either want to use it as an AWN applet (see above) or stand-alone. To use it as a stand-alone dock, press ALT + F2 and type: "dockx".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

DockBarX 0.39.7

DockBarX 0.39.7 was released more than a week ago and you could already install it in Ubuntu Lucid from its official PPA, but we've uploaded Karmic and Maverick packages too in the WebUpd8 PPA.

DockBarX 0.39.7 comes with some cool new features such as:

- Multiple monitor support: Option to only show windows that is on the current monitor (see advanced tab in preference).
- Popups for group buttons without open windows is not shown anymore, instead there is an option in preference dialog to show tooltips for group buttons without windows.
- The group button menu pops up next to the group button instead of poping up at the mouse pointer.
- DockbarX might be slightly faster and use a little bit less memory in certain situations.
- Popup windows closes when you click outside them or after a delay (600 ms).
- A shorter delay is used when a popup window is open and you move the mouse to another group button to open a new popup window. The delay can be set from the preference dialog.
- Popup windows are closed when a group button action is executed (exceptions are 'show popup' and 'select next/previous window').
- Popup windows can be closed when a window button is clicked. You can set the option from the window button tab in the preference dialog.
- The minimize target (the area a window minimizes to) is now always the group button.

Install the latest DockBarX 0.39.7 in Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala, 10.04 Lucid Lynx or 10.10 Maverick Meerkat:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install dockbarx

And to also install some extra themes:

> sudo apt-get install
>   dockbarx-themes-extra

To also install the AWN applet:

> sudo apt-get install
>   awn-applet-dockbarx

Comment: And how to run it ?? in Ubuntu 11.10 i only see dockbarx preference in the dash