# How do I install dockbarx?

Tags: 11.10, installation, dockbarx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install dockbarx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9364/how-to-install-dockbarx)

How do I install dockbarx on Ubuntu 11.10? When I am going to install it says:

```
dockbarx : Depends: python-gnomeapplet but it is not installable
```

How do I solve this?