# How do I install gnomenu?

Tags: mate

Installing these programs , using parts of the MATE project works. But does another way to install these packages exists ? Using 12.04.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9364/how-to-install-dockbarx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made MateNu (fork of GnoMenu). Working well but:

1. If you enable compositing, you will not get the shadow (compiz, marco).
2. Not compatible with the dock. *(According to [user78138](https://askubuntu.com/users/78138/user78138), this limitation is now fixed, and tested on awn.)*
3. If you enable compositing, you will be a little difficult to open the menu (resolution: double-click menu).

link:

main site: http://airinux.blogspot.com/2012/06/matenu.html

Launchpad site: https://launchpad.net/matenu/

Comment: I have made a MateMenu ( ruinning the mate migrating script),it is compatible to awn,but not to every other dock,panel, whatever.My version doesn't even run in matepanel.

Answer (score 1):

Tilo-Menu works just fine too...

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tilomenu/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCDHz3IbhJ4&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score -2):

This method work for me in ubuntu 12.04 without mate, Opening terminal and typing following commands one after another...And this is gnomenu, not other..

```
cd /tmp && wget -O gnomenu_2.9.1.deb http://goo.gl/rJ9X6


sudo dpkg -i gnomenu_2.9.1.deb


wget -O gnomenu.files.tar.gz http://goo.gl/zZr9l


sudo tar -xzvf gnomenu.files.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/gnomenu/
```

It is working well with cairo dock and awn , except for shutdown where change of command is needed.....